# Android's InputMethodService - how to get unicode characters?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a keyboard...

```
int code = 29; // Key code constant: 'A' key. Constant Value: 29 (0x0000001d)
KeyEvent k = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, code);

InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
ic.sendKeyEvent(k);
```

This code nicely send letter "A" to the application, as it is associated with the code "29", as from here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

But what should I do, if I want to use unicode characters, such as in here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: ic.commitText("ПРЕВЕД МЕДВЕД", 0);

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a keyboard app, and have keyboard layout in xml, you can look at suggestion provided by user [Laurent'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/940745/laurent) in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7390029/1966013):

```
<Key android:codes="946" android:keyLabel="\u03B2"/> 
<Key android:codes="946" android:keyLabel="&946;"/> 
<Key android:codes="946" android:keyLabel="β"/>  
<!-- Warning, you should use UTF-8 encoding for your project files if you use the third solution -->
<!-- all produce the same key with greek β character (unicode \u03B2, decimal 946) -->
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check the [softkeyboard](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/res/xml/qwerty.html)  sample code.

If you are developing a new keyboard(for example for any other language), change the android:code attribute value to the unicode value which you want the keyboard to output.
This works fine and I think you can test it in the same [softkeyboard](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/res/xml/qwerty.html) project.